# Multiple results from one subgroup

Tags: regex

I have this string:
`<own:egna attribute1="1" attribute2="2">test</own:egna>`
I want to catch all attributes with a regexp.

This regexp matches one attribute: `(\s+attribute\d=['"][^'"]+['"])`
But why is it that appending a + like ``(\s+attribute\d=['"][^'"]+['"])+` actually only returns the last matched attribute and not all of them?

How would you change this to return all attributes in separate groups?
I'm actually having more regexp around this, so using functions such as python's findall and equivalents won't do.

Comment: Repeated subexpressions are not supported by all dialects of regex.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @Stephen This was tested using PHP 5.3.2 and Python 2.6.1

Comment: I dunno php, but I'm not sure this is possible in python.  Try using `findall` or `finditer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't - only the last group is accessible. The Python docs state this explicitly:

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible [...]

You'll have to use some language features:

1. In PHP, there's `preg_match_all` that returns all matches.
2. In other languages, you'll have to do this manually: add the `g` modifier to the regex and loop over it. Perl, for example, will manage a string position and return the next match in $1 each time a `/([...])/g` pattern is matched.

Also take a look at [Capturing a repeated group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561/capturing-a-repeated-group).